# Better way to declare properties as protected

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties, ivar

Following [this blog post](http://bhapca.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-access-backing-ivars-for.html), I saw a way to solve the problem I was facing.

My problem, like his, was that I have a class that has a property which must be inherited and accessed in its subclass:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger prop;
@end

@implementation A
    // Don't need to synthesize nowadays
@end

@interface B : A
    // No new properties
@end

@implementation B

- (void)establishValueForProp
{
    _prop = 1; // PROBLEM !!!
}

@end
```

The solution was this:

```
@interface A : NSObject {
    @protected
    NSUInteger _prop;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger prop;
@end
```

What I'm wondering is if there is another way to declare properties as protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another common way of doing it, is by creating a separate .h file (ASubclass.h, for example) and adding something like this:

```
@interface A (Protected)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger prop;

@end
```

Subclassers can then import this .h and will have access to this method. Note that since categories can't add properties, you'll have to redefine this property in `A`'s private `interface` (class extension). The category will then provide public access to this property. Apple takes this exact approach with UIGestureRecognizer.h and UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h (where UIGestureRecognizer.h exposes more methods, intended for subclassers to override).

The concept of protected (or private, for that matter) methods doesn't really exist, and this is only a way to somewhat achieve similar functionality.

Personally, I just create a category in the (only) .h file of the class that exposes an otherwise public property. This way it's separated from the main public interface, and since it's possible to get to private properties anyway, I think this approach is good enough.

Comment: Note that in contrast to my answer, this requires you to separately redefine (or otherwise provide accessor methods for) the property in the main class interface or a class extension. Using a class extension instead of a named category in the subclass header doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: I thought there could only be one class extension? Or is it one class extension per .h?

Comment: @Scott, No, as far as I know, there's no limit to the number of class extensions for a class, and they don't have to be separated one-per-.h (afterall, when you #import a .h, it's essentially inserted inline with the file being compiled). This, with three class extensions for a single class, compiles and runs just fine: https://gist.github.com/armadsen/8618759

Answer (score 3):

The way I typically do this is to create a second header, called e.g. "ClassName_ForSubclasses.h". Inside that header file, add a class extension with the properties and methods you want subclasses to be able to call and override. Then, subclasses can import that header, while other users of the class(es) don't see it.